# htaccess redirect from subdirectory to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up a local instance of a php site working in a server, in the "/" directory. My local instance will work in my development environment in a "/subdirectory/".

I'm trying to translate *.htaccess* to adapt to this, but I always get a 404. This is original *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^my-nice-url$ /index.php?p=ugly_url
```

And these are my tries:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mylocaldirectory/

# Not in local! RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
# Not in local! RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^my-nice-url$ /index.php?p=ugly_url
```

Also

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^(.*)my-nice-url$ /index.php?p=ugly_url
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you want make a user friendly url, i do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(your-nice-url)$  ($1)/$2/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(your-nice-url)/$ $1/index.php?p=$2 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(your-nice-url)$  ($1)/$2/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(your-nice-url)/$ $1/index.php?p=what-ever-you-need [L]
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: I still get a 404, in my apache log I see File does not exist: C:/wwwroot2/example.com/my-nice-url  it's truth it doesn't exist but I'd like index.php?p=ugly_url to show up